# In built Pandas plotting tool for plotting integers against string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of values loaded in to data frame like.
So there are multiple values associated with sting 'B', 'K' and 'U'.
Is there a inbuilt way to plot using pd.DataFrame.plot.scatter() to scatter plot multiple values associated with each alphabet without using ax.set_xticklabels?

`pd.DataFrame.plot.scatter()` does not seem to work ?

It says key error: Alphabet

```
Alphabet     Modulus
B             50
K             60
U            100
B            140
K            150
U             80
B             90
K            110
U            150
B            130
K             85
U            120
```

Comment: What do you want the `x-axis` to be? `1,2,3...`?